# How to join multiple tables in SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am working in android studio & I'm new in SQLite. I can't understand how to relate multiple tables in SQLite.

My problem:
I have 3 tables, say -

```
         table_users(name, Id), 
         table_courses(title, code), 
         table_students(name, id)
```

I need to inner join these tables.

For each column of table_users, I want to create multiple column of table_courses. And for each column of table_courses, I want to create multiple column of table_students.
And when I log in with an user, I want to see all courses added for this user. And when I click on a course_name in my app, I want to see all students under that course. How to do this? I am little bit confuse about the query. Should I add both table_user & table_courses column in table_students?

Comment: What's the difference between `users` and students`? I guess you can get away with only one table instead of two (plus the other one). Then you must have a field to link the different tables - please, search for SQL relations (or, more specifically, SQLite relations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest 3 tables but not the 3 that you have defined.

The students and users tables simply replicate each other so those two could become 1 table.

The cousres table is fine as is.

The third table is a table used to map/associate/relate a student to a course and would allow a many-many type relationship. That is a student could have many courses and each course could have many students.

So the tables could be :-

table_users(id, name, other columns if needed)
table_courses(code, title) (where code is unique)
table_user_course (studentId, courseCode)

Perhaps consider the following demonstration of how the above could be used including two queries that include using the relationships :-

```
/* Recreate tables if they exist */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS courses;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_courses;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS courses (code TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_courses(userId INTEGER, courseCode INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(userID,courseCode));

/* Add some testing data */
INSERT INTO users (name) /*<<<< Let sqlite generate the id so just insert the 1 value for name */ 
    VALUES ('Mary') /* Mary will be id 1 */,('Fred') /* Fred will be id 2 */,('Sue') /* Sue will be id 3 */
;
INSERT INTO courses /* no need to define columns to insert into as all columns */
    VALUES ('M100','Mathematics'),('E100','English Language'),('S100','Science'),('G100','Geography')
;
INSERT INTO user_courses
    VALUES
        (1,'M100'),(1,'S100') /* Mary enrolled in maths and science */,
        (3,'G100'),(3,'E100'),(3,'S100') /* Sue in Geog, English and science */,
        (2,'M100'),(2,'E100'),(2,'S100') /* Fred in Maths, English andd Science */
;

SELECT name, code, title FROM users JOIN user_courses ON userID = id JOIN courses ON code = courseCode ORDER BY name;
SELECT title, count() AS enrolled, group_concat(name) 
FROM courses 
    JOIN user_courses ON user_courses.courseCode = courses.code
    JOIN users ON users.id = user_courses.userId
GROUP BY courses.code
;


/* Cleanup testing environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS courses;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_courses;
```

The first query, list according (ODRER BY) to name the related rows (the mapping table is used just for that the values are not show as they would be of little use to an end user)

[image]

The second query utilises some aggregate functions that combine values according to how the selected rows are grouped (GROUP BY) (broken into sub-sets). The grouping being by the course. The **count** function returns the number of rows in the set, the **group_concat** functions returns a comma-separated list of all the values of the specified expression (typically a column) within the set.

[image]